# In build scripts, is there any way to continue on error?

Tags: build

I sometimes build stuff from source, and sometimes there is a `configure` script. For instance, I try to build `ngspice` (currently on `cygwin`, but the same goes for Linux too), so I run its `configure` script, and it halts with a requirement for `bison`; I install that, and then I get:

```
configure: error: Flex is required for building XSPICE
```

... etc.

So, instead of running `configure` each time a new package has to be installed, is there some standard way to have `configure` scripts run to the end and report all errors on the way?